# How to add Store View Filter in Custom Listing Grid In Magento 2.X?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, adminhtml, filter

I have created a custom module in my Magento 2.3.1 site. The module has Admin Listing Grid and Add/Edit view. My site is multi-store site, Now I want to display "Store View" filter in listing grid at admin. Can you anyone guide me to add it? I also want to filter the listing result as per the filtered store id. Please see attached screenshot of Magento CMS module filters. I want to add same "Store View" filter in my custom module listing grid. 
I have used "ui_component" .xml file to display listing grid in my module. So, Please help to add "Store View" filter in "ui_component" xml file.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: try this http://blog.a2bizz.com/index.php/2017/09/12/magento-2-show-multiple-store-view-in-admin-custom-module-grid/ or this https://www.mageworx.com/blog/how-to-add-column-with-filter-to-magento-2-orders-grid/

Comment: @MichaelHa Thank you for the reply, but this is not helpful to me. I want to add "Store View" filter not any custom filter.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column similar to this in your ui component for the grid page or update the already existing one with options and config nodes just as below.

```
<column name="some_name">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store view</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<listingToolbar ...>` key to your XML file if you don't have it.

Then, add the following into it:

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    ...
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <filterSelect name="store_id" provider="${ $.parentName }">
            <settings>
                <options class="Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store\Options"/>
                <caption translate="true">All Store Views</caption>
                <label translate="true">Store View</label>
                <dataScope>store_id</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </filterSelect>
    </filters>
</listingToolbar>
```

**Please note:**

The `...` means you have to mix this code with the rest of your `listingToolbar` settings if you already have it.

Also, mix the `filterSelect` with the rest of your filters settings if you already have a <filters ...> key in your XML file.

The dataScope `store_id` is a reference to your Store ID column. In a normal situation, its name should be `store_id` but it could be also different. If it doesn't work, check if your name attribute of your Store ID column matches with your `<columns ...>` settings.